# Prevent re-render with expensive timer

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need a timer in one of my main screens, which has to run every 10ms (which is really expensive, I know. It has to play a sound for a certain cadence).

I tried to use a custom hook to extract the time from the screen like so:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// constants
const PLAYER_INTERVAL = 10;

const useStepSoundInterval = (
    receivedCadence: number,
    handleSound: () => void,
) => {
    const [playerTimeCount, setPlayerTimeCount] = useState(0);
    const [playerTimerStep, setPlayerTimerStep] = useState(0);
    let timerSound: NodeJS.Timeout;

    useEffect(() => {
        timerSound = setInterval(handleStepSoundInterval, PLAYER_INTERVAL);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(timerSound);
            setPlayerTimeCount(0);
            setPlayerTimerStep(0);
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (receivedCadence) {
          setPlayerTimerStep((playerTimerStep) => playerTimerStep + 0.1);
          
          if (1 / receivedCadence * PLAYER_INTERVAL <= playerTimerStep) {
            setPlayerTimerStep(0);
            handleSound();
          }
        }
    }, [receivedCadence, playerTimeCount]);

    const handleStepSoundInterval = () => {
        setPlayerTimeCount((playerTimeCount) => playerTimeCount + 1);
    };

};

export default useStepSoundInterval;
```

Then I call it like that on my screen:

```
useStepSoundInterval(
    receivedCadence,
    handleSound,
);
```

I thought, if I extract it, as a hook, from the screen, it would prevent to re-render the JSX all the time, but it does re-render every 10ms, which is a tiny bit expensive :)

Can I somehow use React.Memo? I failed to implement it.

Comment: I may do a child component, which returns an empty <View>, do my timer in there and hope, that the parent screen doesn't re-render then. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I did the same what I did as a hook as a component and return an empty <View>. Now my timer seems to be disconnected from the main screen.